# Could't sign you in! This browser or app may not secure. Flutter WebView Google & Facebook Sign In Problem

Tags: flutter, webview, facebook-login, google-signin

I have WordPress site which allow user to sign in with Google and Facebook. User login with Google and Facebook works well on Browser.

I tried to embed my website to Flutter using

```
  flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.11
  flutter_inappwebview: ^3.3.0+3
```

but for Google got problem as image bellow:

[image: Could't sign you in! This browser or app may not secure.]

For Facebook Sign In, it stuck on loggin with message: **Please close this tab**

[image: Facebook Login, Please close this tab.]

```
       WebviewScaffold(
        withJavascript: true,
        withLocalUrl: true,
        geolocationEnabled: true,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        userAgent: kAndroidUserAgent,
        url: selectedUrl,
        javascriptChannels: jsChannels,
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Widget WebView'),
        ),
        withZoom: true,
        withLocalStorage: true,
        hidden: true,
        initialChild: Container(
          color: Colors.redAccent,
          child: const Center(
            child: Text('Waiting.....'),
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score 3):

Try typing the following text in the user agent field.

**"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; Redmi Note 8 Pro) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.88 Mobile Safari/537.36"**

Comment: its working , Amazing

Comment: @Aksoyhlc please how do I include support for iPhones? And so that it displays the accurate device name that is trying to sign in with the Google account?

Comment: @Dangdat Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_2_9; like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/535.9 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Chrome/53.0.1708.186 Mobile Safari/535.1

You can try as